# No audio on Mac Pro after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: macos, audio

I have looked at other people's problems regarding this issue but the way they solved it cannot fix my problem as I don't have any options to change anything. see images.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to troubleshoot these problems? You mention having tried other people's solutions, but you don't indicate what they were. Did you try all the suggestions in this post? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152649/sound-not-working-when-running-os-10-yosemite

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Yosemite and I've been looking for an answer on StackOverflow ever since. I found an answer which was not upvoted so it was harder to find unfortunately, but here is a way which solved my problem:

Open your terminal on your Mac and type in:

`sudo killall coreaudiod`

Press enter and you're done. It should work now.

Hope this helps.